# How to solve "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

1.In article-List component,I pass 'history' to child component article-cell component:

2. In child component(article-cell),I use history.push,but an error  occured.
    this.props.history.push(`/detail/${this.props.data._id}`, {id: this.props.data_id});

```
   return(
            <div>

                {
                    items.map((item,index) => (
                        <ArticleListCell history={this.props.history} key={index} data={item} tags={tags} />
                    ))
                }



            </div>
```

```
 return(
            <div className="ac_container" onClick={
                () => {
                    this.props.history.push(`/detail/${this.props.data._id}`, {id: this.props.data_id});
                    // props.getArticleDetail(props.data_id)
                    // this.props.his
                }
              }
            >
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
onClick
C:/Users/Lee/Documents/Repos/ReactExpressBlog/src/components/ArticleListCell/ArticleListCell.js:18
  15 | return(
  16 |     <div className="ac_container" onClick={
  17 |         () => {
> 18 |             this.props.history.push(`/detail/${this.props.data._id}`, {id: this.props.data_id});
     | ^  19 |             // props.getArticleDetail(props.data_id)
  20 |             // this.props.his
  21 |         }
View compiled、
```

Comment: What's the value of `this.props.history` in article-List component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to send the history as props to child component, by default **react-router-dom** provides **withRouter** to get **history** object in functional component.
see the example below

```py
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
function Test(props) {
    const { match, location, history } = props;
    const handleClick = () => {
        history.push('/home')
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>redirect</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Test);
```

see clear example by demo code here

[image: Code sample]